# check for existing record

Tags: c++

```
class Catalog  {


bool BookCopy;

public:
string BookTitle;
Catalog()
{

  BookCopy = false;

}

Catalog(string Title, bool Copy)
{
BookTitle = Title; 
BookCopy = Copy;
 }


void SetTitle(string Title)  {BookTitle = Title; }

void SetBookCopy(bool Copy) {BookCopy = Copy; }

string GetTitle()    { return BookTitle; }

bool GetCopy() { return BookCopy; }

};

class BookList  { 
     vector<Catalog> List;  
 vector<Catalog>::iterator Transit;




public: 


 void Fill(); 

 void Show(); 


}; 

 void BookList::Fill()   //Create book record
  { 
string Title;
    bool Copy;


Catalog Buffer;

cout << "Enter book information, Stop To quit" << endl; 
cout << "-------------------------- " << endl;
while(true)
{ 
     cout << "Title: "; 
     getline(cin, Title); 
     if(Title == "Stop") 
     break;

     for(Transit = List.begin() ; Transit != List.end() ; Transit++ ) {
    if(Transit->GetTitle() == Title) {
      Copy = true;
     }
      else 
       Copy = false;
    }
```

I want to check if an identical title exists when making a new record.  If it exists then to assign 1 to Copy otherwise leave it as 0.  When I make a record with an identical title 1 does not get assigned to copy.

Comment: Seems like the code is not complete.

Comment: Please show where List comes from. Does that already have the data in it or are you supposed to be adding each Title to List as you enter them.

Comment: Could you also paste the `GetTitle` function?

Comment: I edited the original code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is homework, you should probably rewrite it almost completely.

First of all, you should probably define "Book" as a class, and define an extraction operator for it:

```
class Book { 
    string title;
    string additional;
public:
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Book &b) {
        std::getline(is, b); 
        return is;
    }

    // see reason for this below
    bool operator<(Book const &other) const {
       return title < other.title; 
    }
};
```

I'd note, however, that "copy" does not seem to be a characteristic of the book itself. For the most part, what you really have is a list of books, and some number of copies (maybe one) of any particular title. For that, I'd do something like:

```
std::map<Book, int> BookList;
```

To use a `map`, however, your "keys" (`Book`s, in this case) have to be comparable -- i.e., `operator<` has to return a meaningful result for them (which is why I defined it above).

Now, instead of a "copy" member in the Book class, we just have a number of copies of a given title in the book list:

```
std::cout << "Please enter book title:";
Book b;
std::cin >> b;    // User enters book data

// Increment the number of copies of this title.
// Basically works out to:
// If the title wasn't in the list, 
//     inserts it with a value of 0, then increments it to 1.
// else
//     increment # of copies of title already in list
//
++BookList[b];
```

Note that this is also considerably more efficient than what you were doing -- it does a (logarithmic) tree search for each existing book instead of a linear search.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem in the original program: the for(Transit) loop should be terminated when a duplicate title is found, instead it continues comparing the other recorded titles as well. Therefore, unless a duplicate title is the very last in the list, copy will always be false.

This is one of the problems where I am loath to give an answer, because I think the OP would learn more from advice on how to find the problem - namely using a debugger (or cout) to print the values of Copy and Transit on every iteration.